# command object no binding property

Tags: grails

I am trying to implement some command object validation, but one property of command object is  not binding its always return null

Domain class

```
package ni.sb

class PurchaseOrder implements Serializable {
  Date dateCreated
  Date dutyDate
  String invoiceNumber
  BigDecimal balance
  String typeOfPurchase

  Date lastUpdated

  static constraints = {
    dutyDate nullable:false, validator: { dutyDate ->
    def today = new Date()

    if (dutyDate <= today) {
      "notMatch"
    }
   }
   invoiceNumber blank:false, unique:true
   balance nullable:true
   typeOfPurchase inList:["Contado", "Credito"], maxSize:255
 }
```

}

This is the command object

```
class PurchaseOrderCommand implements Serializable {
  Date dutyDate
  String invoiceNumber
  String typeOfPurchase

  static constraints = {
   importFrom PurchaseOrder
 }
```

}

Here is the controller action

```
def actName(PurchaseOrderCommand cmd) {
  if (cmd.hasErrors()) {
    println params.dump()
    println cmd.dump()

    return
  }
}
```

dutyDate is not binding, after i try dumb() in params and cmd i get this

snippet params.dump()

**dutyDate:2014-09-25**

snippet cmd.dump()

**dutyDate=null**

I hope you can help me

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect `cmd.errors` I expect you will see the error there.

If your date request parameters are formatted like "2014-09-25" and you are using a recent version of Grails then something like this should work:

```
import org.grails.databinding.BindingFormat

class PurchaseOrderCommand implements Serializable {
    @BindingFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
    Date dutyDate
    String invoiceNumber
    String typeOfPurchase
}
```

Alternatively you could set "yyyy-MM-dd" as one of the default formats in `Config.groovy`.

```
// grails-app/conf/Config.groovy
grails.databinding.dateFormats = ['yyyy-MM-dd',
                                  'MMddyyyy', 
                                  'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S', 
                                  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"]
// ...
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I think we introduced `BindingFormat` in Grails 2.3.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, i will try to implement this suggestion.

Comment: This example does not work (at least in grails 2.5.2), is missing the annotation attribute `code`, so `@BindingFormat(code='yyyy-MM-dd')` is the correct.

Comment: @iberck "so @BindingFormat(code='yyyy-MM-dd') is the correct" - this is not correct.  The value of the `code` attribute isn't the date format.  It is the message key that can be used to go retrieve the date format from a message bundle.  Unless your message code is `yyy-MM-dd`, then what you show there shouldn't work.  If it does, that is a bug.

Comment: @iberck See the Grails 2.5.2 code at https://github.com/jeffbrown/datebinding/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy and https://github.com/jeffbrown/datebinding/blob/master/test/unit/demo/DemoControllerSpec.groovy.

Comment: Using 2.5.4 and having the same issue, using the config binding formats and the annotation method, the command object date doesn't bind.

Comment: @Dave I can't recreate that.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and provide a sample app which demonstrates the behavior, I can take care of it.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Hi Jeff, in my particular scenario, I'm using a webflow, maybe this has some influence.

Comment: " I'm using a webflow, maybe this has some influence." - Unlikely.  The data binder doesn't know anything about web flow and the behavior of the binder does not change if the web flow plugin is installed.